# ReadStream is not reading uploaded file

Tags: node.js, fs, createwritestream

I tried this lines to Creating ReadSteam with uploaded files and pipe to WriteStream:

```
var f2 = req.files.f2;

var f2read = fs.createReadStream(f2)
var f2write = fs.createWriteStream("./trailers/" + id + ".mkv")
f2read.pipe(f2write)
```

but this error appeared:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can check - the variable f2 is not a string but an object. I suggest open the documentation of the tool which is used to handle file uploading on your project, as usual they already provide interfaces to receive Streams. [Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)